# Javascript total math of string with multiple operators for js calculator

Tags: javascript

I am a student working on a javascript calculator project.
I would like to take an array with multiple operators and output an answer, for example;

```
var equationArray = ["1", "+", "3", "/", "4", "+", "10", "*", "2"]
var answer = 22;
```

The current code version breaks up the array before and after the operator symbol.

```
if (pressedOperator === '=') {
firstpart = parseFloat(equationArray[0]);
operator = equationArray[1];
secondpart = parseFloat(equationArray[2]);
}
```

What would be the best way to total the array without using eval or regex?

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3daddict/8g6qrp5f/4/

Comment: `1+3/4+10*2 = 21.75`, not `22`. Unless we're rounding the answer?

Comment: or not using BODMAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the Array on `""` and then use the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) to get the mathematical value of the String.

```js
var equationArray = ["1", "+", "3", "/", "4", "+", "10", "*", "2"];
function getMathematicalValue(str){
  return new Function('return ' + str)();
}
var answer = getMathematicalValue(equationArray.join(""));
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what restrictions OP is under that he wasn't allowed to use `eval()`, and if `Function` would fall under that same umbrella. That said, it wasn't mentioned, and this answer works well. Nice job.

Comment: Looks very promising thank you for the suggestion. Now I am trying to figure out how to implement it in the code. We were not allowed to use Eval for the project to find other ways to make it work.

Comment: Function constructor is just another form of `eval()`, e.g. executing code contained in a string. The actual solution to this is kind of fun, it involves a loop consuming array items two at a time. I'd try to do that.

Comment: @jpsimons can you give me an example so I can try to figure it out?